# Parse line from text, rename

Tags: java, regex, string

Still rather new to the giant world of coding so excuse me if there's some program that accomplishes what I needed to do this entire time.

With that out of the way, I have this string:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="001" class="rare1">1★
        <td><img src="icons/weapons/tdagger/tdagger_001.png" />
        <td><a class="fancybox" href="icons_large/weapons/tdagger/tdagger_001.png" rel="tdagger" title="Twin Dagger">
            <img class="large" src="icons_large/weapons_preview/tdagger/tdagger_001.png" /></a>
        <td><a onclick="select_all(this)">ツインダガー</a><br><a href="weapon_04.php#001" title="ツインダガー">Twin Dagger</a>          <td>1<br>S-ATK
        <td><img class="small" src="icons/small/small_01.png" /><br><img class="small" src="icons/small/small_02.png" /><br><img class="small" src="icons/small/small_03.png" />
        <td>59  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>61  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>63  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>66  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>69  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>71  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>74  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>77  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>81  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>84  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>88  <br>0   <br>0
        <td>Common Drop<br>Normal
        <td class="desc">
        <td class="desc">
            <img class="small" src="icons/small/class_04.png" title="Fighter"/>         <td class="desc">
    </tr>
```

multiply this by about 90 times, and you'll have the text file I have on my hands right now. If you're interested in seeing the txt file in it's entirety, you can look here(http://puu.sh/mGb28/7358869e42.txt).

I also have a correlating amount of images that go along with this text.

What I need to do is to get the english title(which in this case is)

> Twin Dagger

and then rename the matching image file(which I already have downloaded)

> tdagger_001.png

to

> TwinDaggerIcon.png

My original thoughts on this were to use regex to get the title and correlating image file name, then write these into a new text file. I would then use bluej(java; the ide I'm familiar with), to rename the files by reading through the text file(with only title & image names).

I iterate through my list of image files, if the image name is equal to an image name in text file, then I change it's name to the title(without whitespace) and apend "Icon.png" to the end.

Frankly however, I'm not that familiar with regex and what I've gotten so far really doesn't look like something I can use. Any help with the comparison of names and renaming files would be a plus.

Comment: hi, you can use a DomParser it'd be more easy to handle tags and attributs

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood the main problem is the renaming. I guess you want to keep you pic in the same directory as before so you can use

```
Path source = // image source
Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("newname"));
```

I hope it works for you.

Edit:
Another option is to make two instances of `File` class and the just call renameTo method for one of them and in the brackets to pass the second instance of file:

```
// File (or directory) with old name
File file = new File("oldname");

// File (or directory) with new name
File file2 = new File("newname");

if (file2.exists())
   throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

// Rename file (or directory)
boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);

if (!success) {
   // File was not successfully renamed
}
```

After that you can use Filewriter to save it on the machine.